# create exeutable WAR file springboot without maven/Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a simple springboot application with inbuild tomcat which works fine when I am running it as JAVA Application in Eclipse. I tried to export this as a WAR file and tried to run it in Windows command line and also in UNIX box. I tried to execute it like below,

```
java -jar C:\Users\Iam\Documents\SpringHelloWorld.war main.java.com.controller.SpringBootWebApplication
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file C:\Users\Iam\Documents\SpringHelloWorld.war

java -cp C:\Users\Iam\Documents\SpringHelloWorld.war main.java.com.controller.SpringBootWebApplication
Error: Could not find or load main class main.java.com.controller.SpringBootWebApplication
```

I just export it as a WAR file, should i need to define anything before exporting it as WAR in Springboot ( note: i am not using maven or gradle )

Below is my project structure :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYtZU.png)

Comment: You should use Maven or Gradle. Else you won't be able to build a proper JAR/WAR for Spring Boot.

Comment: Use the appropriate tools, anything else is a waste of time and energy. Don't try to move your furniture with your sports car, when you know that using that truck of your friend will get the job done much better and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is possible to do this without Maven/Gradle, but I would never take this approach.

Even considering the best case, you will end up re-creating what others have created in the Spring Boot parento pom.xml or in his Gradle equivalent, so why you would waste a lot of time recreating what is already created by someone else? If you really want to know how the war is created, then take a look in Spring Boot parent pom, but you should limit your work to wrap what is ready for production in order to compose your solution.

Also consider that Maven and Gradle are constantly developed and updated, along everything belongs to their ecosystems. If you plan to replace them, then you should be prepared to mantain and develop alone your own build platform, which is a non-trivial effort.

Better include Maven or Gradle, you'll be more productive.